# How to colour code a DataGrid row in an MVVM Light Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm binding a `DataGrid` to a model and want to change the colour of the row based on the data.  For example, if a model property error is true.  Here's what I currently have:

```
<Grid Name="MyGrid">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">                    
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="{Binding Path=Error}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field1" Binding="{Binding Field1}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field2" Binding="{Binding Field2}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field3" Binding="{Binding Field3}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field4" Binding="{Binding Field4}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This approach gives me the compile time error:

> ```
> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Property' property of type 'Trigger'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.
> ```

Comment: This is what [StyleSelectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector.aspx) are for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RowStyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyleselector.aspx) for that:

```
public class MyStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public Style RegularStyle { get; set; }

    public Style ErrorStyle { get; set; }

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        var model = item as YourModel;

        // Avoid possible NullReferenceException
        if (model is null) return RegularStyle;

        // Here you determine which style to use based on the property in your model
        if (model.Error)
        {
            return ErrorStyle;
        }

        return RegularStyle;
    }
}
```

Then create it as a resource in your xaml and define your styles

```
        <local:MyStyleSelector x:Key="rowStyleSelector">
            <local:MyStyleSelector.RegularStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </Style>
            </local:MyStyleSelector.RegularStyle>
            <local:MyStyleSelector.ErrorStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Style>
            </local:MyStyleSelector.ErrorStyle>
        </local:MyStyleSelector>
```

And use it in your grid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" RowStyleSelector="{StaticResource rowStyleSelector}">
```

Hope this helps